Как прикрепить фото к тексту aiogram
Возник вопрос, как я могу отправить фото прикрепившее к тексту, но и с Inline, Keyboard кнопками?
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher,types,F
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
import click as kb

bot = Bot('TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def cd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"⚡️Добро пожаловать в Glannnzy Shop, {message.from_user.first_name}!⚡️\n Это Магазин который предостовляет  услуги  по продажам: подписок,пополнение баланса различных игр.",
    reply_markup=kb.main_kb)

@dp. message()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    msg = message.text.lower()

    if msg == 'магазин️':
        await message.answer('Выбери услугу:',reply_markup=kb.game)

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

executor.start_polling(dp)


Возможный дубликат вопроса: Python | Aiogram Как прикрепить фото к тексту, а не текст к фото?

Для того чтобы отправить фото с текстом, а так-же Inline-клавиатурой можно использовать код ниже
await message.answer_photo(photo=YOUR_PHOTO, caption='YOUR_CAPTION', reply_markup=kb.YOUR_KEYBOARD)

